# Is it possible to get a "screen shot" of only a single div

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, image-processing

I want users to be able to take a picture programmatically of a design they have made on my site . The design would be in a div that is a panorama that extends off both left/right edge of the screen.

Basically I would create a .jpg, .png, etc of that div and it's contents.

Is that possible with image magic and a combination of other plugins?

Comment: This link looks helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to download a 'screenshot' of only a single div by using the HTML2Canvas (here's the link: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library. What this code does is generate a canvas based on the HTML of a div, but doesn't display it, then it converts the canvas to a image (in this case a png image file) then provides a download link connected to the generated image:

HTML:

```
<div id="capture"><h2>This should save to a image</h2><p>Amazing!</p></div>
<p id="notice"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
html2canvas($("#capture"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas){
    img = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "<a href='"+img+"' download='download.png'>Click here</a> to download the image";
  }
});
```

Here's a link to the working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xanco/KJ5s5/
Don't hesitate to contact me if you have more questions